# Jquery menu UI. How to display selection value in specified <li>

Tags: jquery-ui

I have nested unordered lists to create a Jquery UI menu that expands when you hover over the first menu option. What I want to happen is for a menu selection to be displayed in the place of the first menu option you see once you select it. For some reason using .val or .html isn't working for me. Here is my code.

```
//this is where I try to take the selection and put it in in the <li> with the id 'input'.

<script>
 $(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu({
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var selection = ui.item.text();
    $("#input").html() = selection;
}
});
}); 
</script>

// the options below "Choose Activity" expand when you hover over "Choose Activity".
```

I want one of the selections 
to take the place of "Choose Activity" once it is selected.

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>
        <a href="#" id="input">Choose Activity?</a> 

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Run Marathon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weight lifting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Swimming</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
          </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
         //another line item
   </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function which either gets/sets the innerHTML of the given element. Since it an function you need to pass the content as an argument to the function call.

It should be `$("#input").html(selection);` not `$("#input").html() = selection;`